# Customize search so it only indexes approved documents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, search, crawling

I have a document library which is using approval work flow. I have search application running that indexes everything. I want to tweak that search application so it only indexes those documents in that library which are approved. Any documents which are not approved should not be indexed by search.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this workflow result in an approved document being "published"? If so, you could set the crawl account to only have permissions to view published items instead of all items.

Here is some related information: [How does SharePoint Search handle pending (unapproved) items?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14216/how-does-sharepoint-search-handle-pending-unapproved-items)